# What is the best way to manage microservice issue or bug on git

Tags: git, microservices, issue-tracking

Micro-Service is about having many projects on git within different repositories.

So, what is the best way to manage an issue, when there is a bug which needed to fix the code on multiple services?

Comment: "*Micro-Service is about having many projects on git within different repositories*" - no, it's not.

Comment: Microservices is essentially an alias for service-oriented *architecture*. Once you get the marketing fluff out of the way, there is no difference. It has nothing to do with issue tracking or version control. Systems contained multiple projects, repositories and databases 15 years ago too when SOA started and earlier, when COM+ and CORBA were used.

Comment: There are no clear answers. Obviously, you need a way to separate issues by service, but that doesn't mean you need a separate Redmine project or subproject for each service. It's the most common solution though. Git repos is a different thing. How independent are the **business projects*? If 10 services are developed in parallel, there is no point in juggling 10 different repos and trying to keep labels and releases in sync

Comment: `when there is a bug which needed to fix the code on multiple services` -- if you have this then you don't really have microservices. What you have is a stovepipe. Microservices are completely independent of each other. Think about facebook or twitter logins. Those are microservices you use. When you have a bug you either complain to facebook or fix your code, you never do both at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: You have to open specific issues/bugs on each repository regarding the specific shortcomings of the service in the repository. The microservices architectural style is all about loose coupling, so an issue should in general be local and treated as such. It is expected that a service is owned by a dedicated team that will be able to fix the specific issue in their service, but nothing in other teams services anyway.

If in your specific architecture it happens often that you find yourself fixing a single issue in many services you probably have to rethink the service boundaries because they may not be as loosely coupled as desirable. Note that finding the right service boundaries is probably the hardest problem when applying the microservices architectural style.

Here is a further [read](https://auth0.com/blog/introduction-to-microservices-part-4-dependencies/).

Answer (score 0):

If they are really different code in different repos (but just logically correlated), then file multiple bugs each against one repo. If you use a more advanced issue tracking system (e.g., Jira) instead of github's own (rudimentary) issue tracking, you can create a overarching bug that depends on the individual repo's bugs.

Like Oswin said, I would also suggest thinking about if the code can also be physically shared between those repos. If so, do it. Put it in a separate repo and maybe use git submodule to link them together. Micro-service architecture != not sharing code between micro-services.